# How to add lat long values into the database from CSV file

Tags: node.js, postgresql, import, insert

My node based web application asks the user to upload the lat long as csv file. The file is uploaded using blob storage method. But now i cannot import the file directly into postgres database as the table contains columns ID, created time,lat, long while the csv file only contains lat and long info. The table might contain previous values due to this reason i guess import might not work and I guess insert is the only option.

Please help me with how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should import the lat/long data in a temporary table first.
If the `lat_long.csv` file has the following structure:

```
lat, long
41.99646, 21.43141
40.24555, 20,24536
39.24152, 25.263634
```

Then you can create a temporary table:

```
CREATE TABLE lat_long_temp (lat DECIMAL, long DECIMAL);
```

And import the data into the table with the following command:

```
COPY lat_long_temp FROM 'path-to-the-file' CSV HEADER DELIMITER ',';
```

Where the `path-to-the-file` is replaced with the path of your `lat_long.csv` file.

After that, you can query this table and add the results in the table by attaching a value for the `created_time` column.

So, if your result table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE result_table (
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  created_time TIMESTAMP,
  latitude DECIMAL,
  longitude DECIMAL
);
```

You can insert the data from the `lat_long_temp` table with the following query:

```
INSERT INTO result_table (created_time, latitude, longitude)
    SELECT now(), lat, long
    FROM lat_long_temp;
```

Note that I assumed that your `ID` column is an auto-incremented column and because of that there is no need to set the value for that column.
If your `ID` is not auto-generated, you will have to add value in the insert statement for that column as well.

Answer (score 0):

If the other column have default values or are populated by triggers, you can copy only the lat/long columns from the CSV file:

```sql
COPY my_table(latitude, longitude) 
FROM 'path-to-the-file' CSV HEADER DELIMITER ',';
```